# Dynamically Create templateDetails.xml for joomla 2.5 template

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

Is there any software out there, in order to create the templateDetails.xml dynamically?
What I am thinking is a software that I feed with the files that compose the template and the software should create the templateDetails.xml for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of template tools available at the [Joomla Template Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=template%20xml) page that should do the trick.